# xml get attributes javascript doesn't work on childNodes

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I have the following code samples that try to display the `d` attribute of the svg map (found [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9c/India_Karnataka_location_map.svg)).

```
// path method
var node = xmlDoc.getElementById('g67');
console.log(node);

for(var i = 0; i < node.getElementsByTagName('path').length; ++i) {
    console.log(node.getElementsByTagName('path')[i].getAttribute('d'));
}
```

and

```
// childNodes method
var node = xmlDoc.getElementById('g67');
console.log(node);

for(var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
    console.log(node.childNodes[i].getAttribute('d'));
}
```

The former works but the latter doesn't.

I understand I have gone wrong in my concept of nodes in XML DOM. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks You.

Complete code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/prometheansacrifice/7540773)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`childNodes` gives you *all* child nodes. Text nodes, comments, processing instructions, everything.

You want to check the child type (name must be "path"):

```
var node = document.getElementById('g67'), child, i;
console.log(node);

for (i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
    child = node.childNodes[i];
    if (child.nodeName === 'path') {
        console.log(child.getAttribute('d'));
    }
}
```

Also note that `childNodes` gives you *direct children* only, while `getElementsByTagName()` gives you *all descendants*.